# How to compile Webkit for Android (HTC thunderbolt)

Tags: android, browser, compilation, webkit, kernel

I have an HTC thunderbolt LTE device and I want compile a customized Webkit for it.

The purpose is to instrument the Android Browser's loading time which is based on Webkit.

According to the android open source project page, seems only Nexus S and Nexus S 4G are supported.

Can I do this for HTC Thunderbolt?

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you match the version with the legally opened packages provided in HTC's website and re-compile it from there

Comment: @EknathIyer Thanks for your reply. I just realized that WebKit actually is not part of the kernel. It's one layer up, in the library layer if you look at Android Architecture graph. Any more suggestions?